# Ajax PHP not inserting into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using Ajax to get POST values from a form. However, when I try to insert the form values in a database on submit, it doesn't get inserted. I still have no idea why it does not work.

Here is my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="home-sign-up-form">
    <input type="text" name="suFirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-first-name-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suLastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-last-name-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suEmail" placeholder="Email" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-email-text-input">
    <input type="password" name="suPassword" placeholder="Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-password-text-input">
    <input type="password" name="suConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-confirm-password-text-input">
    <input type="text" name="suDisplayName" placeholder="Display Name (you can change this later)" class="text-input-minor" id="sign-up-display-name-text-input">
    <br><font class="text-error" id="sign-up-error-text"></font><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="suRememberMe" value="yes" id="sign-up-remember-me-checkbox"><font id="sign-up-remember-me-text">Remember me</font></label>
    <input name="signUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="sign-up-submit">
</form>
```

My JS (the console.log does go through and work):

```
if (validForm)
{
    console.log("valid form");
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:'form-submit.php',
        data:$('#home-sign-up-form').serialize(),
        success:function(response)
        {
            $suForm.hide();
            $tosppText.hide();
            $mailSentIcon.show();
            $emailSentText.show();
            $emailSentTextEmail.text($suEmail);
            $suBox.css("padding-left", "10px");
            $suBox.css("padding-right", "10px");
        }
    });     
}
```

And my PHP/MySQL:

```
if (isset($_POST['signUp']))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('got');</script>";
    $suFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suFirstName']); 
    $suLastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suLastName']); 
    $suEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suEmail']); 
    $suPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suPassword']);
    $suDisplayName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['suDisplayName']);
    $code = substr(md5(mt_rand()),0,15);

    $query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (firstName,lastName,email,password,displayName,confirmCode,verified)Values('{$suFirstName}','{$suLastName}','{$suEmail}','{$suPassword}','{$suDisplayName}','{$confirmCode},'{$verified}')");
}
```

The alert in the PHP code so I would assume that it isn't getting the 'signUp' POST variable. Thanks so much! Any help is appreciated! :D

Comment: can you add your entire js code (i.e from submition)

Answer (score 0):

You get the signUp post variable when you click on the button. If you are posting via ajax call the button variable will not be available as $_POST variable. Please check any other input value.

Another options is have and hidden input set it to some value. And check it on server side. But it is better to check any normal required input of form instead of having extra input control.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your information! I changed `(isset($_POST['signUp']))j/h

Comment: ^Ignore comment I accidentally pressed enter

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your information! I changed `(isset($_POST['signUp']))` to `(isset($_POST['suEmail']))` and it still didn't work. Thanks so much!

Comment: try to echo json_encode($_POST); without any condition and see the result in browser's console to see it all the data is received by the server.
that will be first debugging.

Then catch the mysql error and echo it or log it. And check the query. That will be second debugging. to check insert.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's getting the POST values. I only see '[]'.

Comment: In that case json serialize data in javascript and console log before sending to know if you are getting in javascript

Comment: Try changing to **$('#home-sign-up-form')[0].serialize()**  if you don't get data.

Comment: I just changed it, however now it doesn't execute `success:function(response)
                    {
                        $suForm.hide();
                        $tosppText.hide();
                        $mailSentIcon.show();
                        $emailSentText.show();
                        $emailSentTextEmail.text($suEmail);
                        $suBox.css("padding-left", "10px");
                        $suBox.css("padding-right", "10px");
                    }` Thanks so much!

Comment: if (validForm)
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify($('#home-sign-up-form')[0].serialize()));
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:'form-submit.php',
        data:$('#home-sign-up-form')[0].serialize(),
        success:function(response)
        {
            $suForm.hide();
            $tosppText.hide();
            $mailSentIcon.show();
            $emailSentText.show();
            $emailSentTextEmail.text($suEmail);
            $suBox.css("padding-left", "10px");
            $suBox.css("padding-right", "10px");
        }
    });     
}

Comment: When I add that 'onclick' code in my html, the POST values are displayed. However, when I add the console.log JSON stringify code I get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].serialize is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if (isset($_POST['signUp'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('got');</script>";
    echo $suFirstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['suFirstName']); 
    echo $suPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['suPassword']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$suFirstName', '$suPassword')";
}

if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli ));
}

echo "1 record added";
```

mysqli_real_escape_string requires two arguments the connection and the string.

You can read more :https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp